# Call model from another component controller in Joomla 3.4

Tags: model, joomla3.4

I am developing `Joomla 3.4 application` where I have to call one component model into another component controller but not call from there.

Support, i have 2 component

```
>> comp1
  model: m1
  controller: c1
>> comp2
  model: m2
  controller: c2
```

I want to call `comp1 model (m1) into comp2 controller (c2).`

I tried using below code:

```
$model    = $this->getModel('m1', '', array());
```

But in `$model` get null value if above code use in `comp1 controller (c1)` then run perfect.

What actually issue is not getting. Any one have a perfect idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but better late than never and I hope it will help other developers.

To call a model from another component you need firstly to include the path of this model:

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/comp1/models', 'Comp1Model');
```

Secondly you have to create an instance of your model:

```
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Model1', 'Comp1Model');
```

After that you should be able to use the methods of your model.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 4 has a excellent dependency injection for this. Old technique not worked for me.

I use this

```
//frontend component Atricle model loaded
$model = Factory::getApplication()->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory()->createModel('Article', 'Site');

$result = $model->getItem('put ID here');
```